# Windows Server 2008 keeps changing time by itself

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I have a VPS that runs Windows Server 2008. The time keeps changing every so often. I haven't been able to find out what triggers this change, but it's usually forward or backward several hours at a time. I don't think the minute changes, it seems that only the hour changes.

Answer (score 2):

The VPS is probably configured to set the time of the VM's it's hosting, and your Windows 2008 VM is probably getting time from the default time source (time.windows.com)...  Try disabling your VPS from setting the VM time and see if that fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This usually indicates some kind of timezone issue between the a VM host, and a VM client.  Check to see if the timezone is correct.

Comment: The timezone is correct

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before when the VM was joined to a domain (not sure if yours is).

I used the following command to fix it:

```
w32tm /config /syncflags:DOMHIER
```